# Получение данных из сервера через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Уважаемые знатоки, нужна ваша помощь. Я хочу получить данные из .php скрипта через ajax и вывести его в div к примеру, но не получается получить данные с сервера.

```
            <div class="results">Ждем ответа</div>
```

есть такой .js файл

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.results').html(data);
      }
    });
```

Код серверного скрипта. Он находится на сервере 127.0.1.1/ajax.php

```
<?php
    echo 'Пример 1 - передача завершилась успешно';
?>
```

Помогите решить проблему

Comment: Проверьте подключение jquery в html. какая ошибка ?

Comment: вообще jquery подключен, а в браузере выдает Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier на  success: function(data) {
        $('.results').html(data);
      }

Comment: а теперь пишет Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: теперь точно не видит jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/plans.js">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                        <span class="sr-only">Открыть навигацию</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="plans.html">Планы</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Конференции <b class="caret"></b> </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Научно-технические</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Экономические</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Гуманитарные</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </li>

                    <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск" value="">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Поиск
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="container-fluid:before">
    <div class="row-fluid:before">
        <div class="span3">  
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="results">Ждем ответа</div>


<input type="text" name="birthdate" value="10/24/1984" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
         url: 'ajax.php',
         success: function(data) {
          $('.results').html(data);
         }
       });

    })

</script>



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the document is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {        
            $('#example1').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });  

        });
</script>
```

Comment: я сделал как у тебя и теперь говорит GET http://127.0.0.1:55345/ajax.php 404 (Not Found), хотя если ввести в адрессной строке http://127.0.0.1/ajax.php то контент скрипта выводится

Comment: @Contact попробуй  так  `url: '/ajax.php'`

Comment: та нет все тот же exception, вообще он пишет Cannot GET /ajax.php

Comment: а ну давай полностью код всей страницы добавь в ответ

Comment: может дело с самим серваком